# Difference between val and def in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am starting with scala and have this confusion in evaluation. If in val, the result is evaluated when declared then why on calling that val name it again gives me the body of the function.

```
scala> val pop = (x:Int,y:Int)=> println(s"$x $y is the number")
pop: (Int, Int) => Unit = <function2>

scala> pop(12,3)
12 3 is the number

scala> pop(12,3) //So is this expression evaluated again ? and if not how is it stored in the memory that if 12 and 3 will come as parameter then that value will be given back.
12 3 is the number
scala> pop
res6: (Int, Int) => Unit = <function2>
//why is it giving the body as it is already evaluated
```

Can a function with no parameters using val can be declared?

```
val som....which only prints say hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, function are *first-class values* so the *value* of `pop` is

```
(x:Int, y:Int) => println(s"$x $y is the number")
```

itself. Such a function-value might look very different from say value `42` but is nevertheless a regular value. For example, contrast the following

```
val i: Int = 42                   // assigning value 42 to name i
val f: Int => String = i => "foo" // assigning value `i => "foo"` to name f
```

It might become clearer if we desugar `pop` definition to

```
val pop: Function2[Int, Int, Unit] = new Function2[Int, Int, Unit] {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Unit = println(s"$x $y is the number")
}
```

where we see `pop` is assigned an instance of `Function2` class which contains an `apply` method. Furthermore `pop(12, 3)` desugars to

```
pop.apply(12,3)
```

where we see `pop(12, 3)` simply calls a method on `Function2` class. Contrast the *evaluation* of `pop`

```
pop
res6: (Int, Int) => Unit = <function2>
```

with function *application* of a function instance `pop` points to

```
pop(12,3)
12 3 is the number
```

`pop` is a **val**ue definition in the sense that we cannot change the function it points to, for example,

```
pop = (i: Int) => i.toString // error: reassignment to val
```

Function with no parameters can be defined like so

```
val g = () => "I am function with no parameters"
g   // evaluates g
g() // applies function pointed to by g
```

Comment: This is a common question in my course. For me, explaining expressions and blocks helps a lot to understand. For example `val f: Int => Unit = { println("creating a function"); x => println(s"evaluating a function with input ${x}") }` - The prints help to show when something is being created / evaluated. Also, replacing **val** with **def** in the previous snippet helps to answer another common question, why not use def to create a function instead of val.